# How to select dynamically created elements using id or class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated

Trying to figure out how to select the divs which I have created dynamically using Javascript, as they are not recognised as a part of dom. New to JS so any insights will be appreciated.

```
function createDiv() {
    count= count+1;
    //creating elements outside - start
    var resultDiv = document.createElement("div");
    resultDiv.className = "result-div";
    var resultDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    resultDiv2.className = "result-div2";
    //end

    if (count%2 != 0) {
        if(count>2) {
            var xyz = document.querySelector(".result-div2");
            xyz.style.display = "none";
            console.log("click 3");
        }

        var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main-div");
        parentDiv.appendChild(resultDiv);

        resultDiv.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("result-div").style.display= "block";
    } else {
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main-div");
        parentDiv.appendChild(resultDiv2);

        console.log("click even");
        document.getElementsByClassName("result-div2").style.display= "block";

        var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName("result-div");
        xyz.style.display = "none";
    }

    console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Directly use the reference i.e. `resultDiv2` instead of `xyz` in `if` block and `resultDiv` in `else`  block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created dynamically using Javascript, as they are not recognized as a part of dom.

No, They are actually as part of the DOM. I guess you are thinking that way because there is no content in the newly created element. You can add some text to the newly created `div` so that you can see that.

[Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object. You have to use index.

```js
function createDiv(){
  var count = 0;
  count = count+1;
  //creating elements outside - start
  var resultDiv = document.createElement("div");
  resultDiv.className = "result-div";
  resultDiv.textContent = "result-1"; //add text here

  var resultDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  resultDiv2.className = "result-div2";
  resultDiv2.textContent = "result-2"; //add text here
  //end
  if (count%2 != 0) {
    if(count>2){
      var xyz = document.querySelector(".result-div2");
      xyz.style.display = "none";
      console.log("click 3");
    }
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main-div");
    parentDiv.appendChild(resultDiv);

    resultDiv.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName("result-div")[0].style.display= "block";
  }
  else{
    console.log(count%2)
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main-div");
    parentDiv.appendChild(resultDiv2);

    console.log("click even");
    document.getElementsByClassName("result-div2")[0].style.display= "block";

    var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName("result-div")[0];
    xyz.style.display = "none";
  }
  console.log(count);
}
createDiv();
```

```css
.result-div {color: red}
```

```html
<div id="main-div"></div>
```